# dart: How to dynamically transfer data?

Tags: javascript, web, dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I want to make a modal window component. In order to be able to transfer it to the head, content, footer.

When you change the data, the changes do not occur in the template:

page.dart

```
ModalComponent MC = new ModalComponent()..init(mTitle:'TitleX');
```

modal.dart

```
class ModalComponent {
  String title = 'sss';
  Future init({String mTitle = 'title'}) async{
    this.title = mTitle;
    print(title);
  }
}
```

modal.html

```
...
<h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
...
```

In the template, I see "sss". In the console I see a print with "TitleX". Why is the data in the template not updated? In the template there is an inscription "sss".

How to correctly do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create components yourself. Angular needs to create them for you so this line won't work:

```
ModalComponent MC = new ModalComponent()..init(mTitle:'TitleX');
```

The instance of ModalComponent that you are changing is completely different than the ModalComponent used in the DOM.